# Не понимаю почему не работает шифровка Цезаря

Tags: javascript

```
function rot13(message){
   message = message.toLowerCase();
   const alphabet = [...'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'];
   alphabet.forEach(letter=> {
      message.replace(letter, alphabet.indexOf(letter) + 13);
   });
      return message;
}
 console.log(rot13('i love you'));
```

Код должен шифровать текст определенным образом. Заменять каждую букву на 13-ую после нее. Я точно где-то ошиблась, но могу постараться объяснить свой алгоритм. В функцию принимаем сообщение. Оно приводится к LowerCase. Затем у нас есть массив алфавита. Мы проходимся по нему и каждую букву заменяем на letter + 13

Comment: И в чём же ошибка? Какой результат и какой ожидаемый?

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей

Comment: не работает так как нужно код. он просто выдает то же самое сообщение, но не зашифрованное .

Answer (score 4):

1. Вы не изменяете message. Метод message.replace ВОЗВРАЩАЕТ новую строку.
2. Вы заменяете букву на номер этой буквы + 13. А вам же надо брать букву под полученным номером.
3. Номер должен быть зациклен. Таким образом 27 буква должна стать первой. Для этого поможет оператор %
4. Заменив вначале одну букву она может заменится потом. Для этого надо вначале перевести строку в номера букв, а только потом уже обратно в строку
5. Вынести 13 стоит как параметр

Да и вообще легче пройтись по каждой букве сообщения, а не по каждой букве алфавита

Исправленный код:

```js
function rot(message, n){
    message = [...message.toLowerCase()]
    const alphabet = [...'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'];
    message.forEach((letter, i) => {
        let index = alphabet.indexOf(letter);
        if (index<0) {return;}
        message[i] = alphabet[(index + n) % alphabet.length]
    });
    return message.join("");
}
```

Comment: спасибо большое !

Comment: а такой вопрос, если введенное слово начинается с заглавной буквы, то как сделать так чтобы при выводе уже зашифрованного слова оно оставалось с заглавной буквой? Методы toLowerCase() или даже charAt(0).toUpperCase() работают на всех словах, даже на тех которые изначально с маленькой буквы введены. Пока не понимаю как исправить это(

Comment: @Julie Проверять, что символ является заглавной буквой (приводите символ в `toUpperCase` и сравнивайте с оригинальным символом), если она заглавная - применять алфавит из заглавных букв.

Comment: @Julie, если вам помог этот ответ, отметьте его как [**принятый**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) (галка напротив ответа).